# What is the formula to get x, y coordinates from a truetype b-spline curve?

Tags: formula, truetype

What is the formula to draw a line in x, y space given b-spline coordinates in a TrueType font?

Comment: Which line are you talking about? There are infinitely many lines in **R^2** ;)

Comment: @Blender: the line defined by the control points of the B-Spline.

Comment: Ohh, so you want to *draw* the spline given it's control points? A line is quite different from a curve, so I'd make that a bit more clear.

Comment: @Blender: thanks but do you know the answer to the question? I don't think you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that Truetype allows for bspline curves AND straight lines within a glyph definition.

If you need to change these commands into a series of MoveTo's and LineTo's you can use the following:

1. Convert the TrueType data into a list of hinted coordinates. This is something your OS can do for you (following code uses the Windows APIs).
2. Walk all coordinates and translate the curves into lines (see code sniplet below):

   ```
   procedure TGlyphEvaluator.EvaluateFromBuffer( Action: TGlyphEvaluatorAction );
   var
       H                                   : TTPOLYGONHEADER;
       C                                   : TTPOLYCURVE;
       Points                              : array of TPointFX;
       P, PE                               : DWORD;
       i, j                                : Integer;
       F                                   : Double;
       PA, PB, PC                          : TPoint;
   begin
       SetLength( Points, 10 );
       P := 0;
       repeat
           // Eat the polygon header
           Move( FBuffer[ P ], H, sizeof( H ) );
           if H.dwType <> TT_POLYGON_TYPE then Break;          // Sanity check!
           PE := P + H.cb;
           Inc( P, sizeof( H ) );
           Points[ 0 ] := H.pfxStart;
           // Eat all the curve records
           while P < PE do begin
               // Get the curve record
               Move( FBuffer[ P ], C, sizeof( C ) - sizeof( TPointFX ) );
               Inc( P, sizeof( C ) - sizeof( TPointFX ) );

               // Get the points from the curve record
               if Length( Points ) < C.cpfx + 1 then Setlength( Points, C.cpfx + 1 );
               Move( FBuffer[ P ], Points[ 1 ], sizeof( TPointFX ) * C.cpfx );
               Inc( P, sizeof( TPointFX ) * C.cpfx );

               case C.wType of
                   TT_PRIM_LINE: begin
                           MoveTo( Action, Points[ 0 ].x.value, Points[ 0 ].y.value );
                           for i := 1 to C.cpfx do
                               LineTo( Action, Points[ i ].x.value, Points[ i ].y.value );
                       end;
                   TT_PRIM_QSPLINE: begin
                           MoveTo( Action, Points[ 0 ].x.value, Points[ 0 ].y.value );
                           PA.X := Points[ 0 ].x.value;
                           PA.Y := Points[ 0 ].y.value;
                           for i := 1 to C.cpfx - 1 do begin   // DrawQSpline is called C.cpfx - 1 times
                               PB.X := Points[ i ].x.value;
                               PB.Y := Points[ i ].y.value;
                               PC.X := Points[ i + 1 ].x.value;
                               PC.Y := Points[ i + 1 ].y.value;
                               if i < C.cpfx - 1 then begin
                                   PC.X := ( PC.X + PB.X ) div 2;
                                   PC.Y := ( PC.Y + PB.Y ) div 2;
                               end;
                               for j := 1 to 8 do begin
                                   F := j / 8;
                                   LineTo( Action, Round( ( PA.x - 2 * PB.x + PC.x ) * Sqr( F ) + ( 2 * PB.x - 2 * PA.x ) * F + PA.x ),
                                       Round( ( PA.y - 2 * PB.y + PC.y ) * Sqr( F ) + ( 2 * PB.y - 2 * PA.y ) * F + PA.y ) );
                               end;
                               PA := PC;
                           end;
                       end;
               end;
               // Update last point.
               Points[ 0 ] := Points[ C.cpfx ];
           end;
           MoveTo( Action, Points[ 0 ].x.value, Points[ 0 ].y.value );
           LineTo( Action, H.pfxStart.x.value, H.pfxStart.y.value );
       until P >= Longword( Length( FBuffer ) );
   end;
   ```

Comment: I see in the revisions.. Can someone explain to me why removing and reinserting <> makes the document render correct again? Hopefully I can do that again myself.

Comment: I don't know. I asked on the meta site and someone came and fixed it. They said my question was an exact duplicate, but when I looked at the thing which they said was an exact duplicate, it didn't help me to understand what had happened here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87423/code-markup-failure-case

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted although I have not been able to check the formula you provided yet. I'll be coming back to this at some point, but thank you.